# Unable to access Azure Vault from Azure Container Instance using System assigned identity

Tags: python, azure, azure-container-instances, azure-managed-identity

I am not able to access vault from Azure Container Instance deployed into a private network with system managed identity. 
My code works fine if i use a service principal to access vault , by pass the environment variable to the container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=bash

my code:

```
import os
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

keyVaultName = 'XXXXXXX'
KVUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)

def secretVal(name):
    logging.debug("Retriving the secret from vault for %s", name)
    val = client.get_secret(name)
    return val.value
```

error

```
2020-05-21:02:09:37,349 INFO     [_universal.py:412] Request URL: 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token'
2020-05-21:02:09:37,349 INFO     [_universal.py:413] Request method: 'GET'
2020-05-21:02:09:37,349 INFO     [_universal.py:414] Request headers:
2020-05-21:02:09:37,349 INFO     [_universal.py:417]     'Metadata': 'REDACTED'
2020-05-21:02:09:37,349 INFO     [_universal.py:417]     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-identity/1.3.1 Python/3.8.3 (Linux-4.15.0-1082-azure-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5)'
2020-05-21:02:09:37,352 DEBUG    [connectionpool.py:226] Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254:80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/default.py", line 105, in get_token
    return super(DefaultAzureCredential, self).get_token(*scopes, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/chained.py", line 71, in get_token
    raise ClientAuthenticationError(message=error_message)
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: No credential in this chain provided a token.
Attempted credentials:
        EnvironmentCredential: Incomplete environment configuration. See https://aka.ms/python-sdk-identity#environment-variables for expected environment variables
        ImdsCredential: IMDS endpoint unavailable
```

The issue seems to something similar to the below.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/8557

i tried pausing my code for the metadata service to be available using the below while creating the instance. But it still doesn't work.

--command-line "/bin/bash -c 'sleep 90; /usr/local/bin/python xxxx.py'"

Comment: it looks like usage of managed identities in container instances deployed to private network is not supported ?https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the managed identity of the Azure Container Instance does not support when you create it in the virtual network. See the limitations:

> You can't use a managed identity in a container group deployed to a
>   virtual network.

The ACI in the virtual network is a preview version currently. All the limitations are shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts#other-limitations). So when it's in the Vnet, use the service principal to authenticate, it's similar to the Managed identity, just display in different styles.